# R shinydashboard: specifying div style width argument as percentage to fit a resizeable JS plot

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny, shinydashboard

**Task**: using `R` and `shinydashboard`, embed a custom Javascript-generated plot in the dashboard body. *Specify width of the plot as percentage*, so that the plot occupies its column (or box) regardless of viewer's screen setup.

**Setup**: `R` (3.5.2), `shiny` (1.2.0) and `shinydashboard` (0.7.1). The dashboard code (simplified reproducible example) is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(

dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("Main", tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("dashboard")
            )
        )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            tabItem("tab1",
                    column(width = 12, 
                           tags$div(id = "main", style = "width: 100%; height: 400px"),
                           tags$script(src = "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.1.0/echarts.min.js"),
                           tags$script(src = "myscript.js")
                    )
            )
        )
    )
 )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The respective Javascript file `myscript.js`, which is to be placed in the `www` subfolder relative to the app file itself, is as follows:

```
// JS Plot with Echarts 4

option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
        type: 'line'
    }]
};

var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
myChart.setOption(option);
```

**Problem**: for some reason, the `100%` specification gets converted to `100px` in the final result, producing this output:

[image: screenshot_plot]

Inspecting the plot I see that `div#main` has indeed the width of 100%, but then it contains another, smaller `div`, which is already `100px` wide:

[image: screenshot2]

To me, it would seem that either `tabItem` or `tabItems` are at fault, because without using them the outcome is correct, and that smaller intermediary `div` takes its width from its parent correctly:

[image: screenshot3]

For completeness, the code for the working version (without `tabItem(s)`) is this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(

    dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(),
        dashboardSidebar(),
        dashboardBody(
            column(width = 12, 
                   tags$div(id = "main", style = "width: 100%; height: 400px"),
                   tags$script(src = "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.1.0/echarts.min.js"),
                   tags$script(src = "myscript.js")
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As you can see, the code is almost identical, aside from the offending functions. I don't see however how a shinydashboard could possibly work without these functions, as they structure the whole application. Is there any workaround you can think of? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very interesting, but yes it seems like a bug/feature in `tabItems`.

By setting the width via css, it just stretches the plot, so that doesnt really work.
I found those little workarounds, that resize the plot on a window resize.

**Option 1:**
To initially resize the window I use `shinyjs` to collapse the sidebar at startup, so the plot gets resized too. This will start the app with a collapsed sidebar.

If you want the sidebar to not be collapsed at startup, you would have to add `collapsed = TRUE` to `dashboardSidebar` and change `addClass` in the server to `removeClass`.

**Option 2:**
If you don't want to use `shinyjs` you could add a little JS-snippet like:

```
jss <- HTML("
$(document).on('shiny:connected', function() {
  $('.sidebar-toggle').click();
});
")
```

with

```
tags$head(tags$script(jss))
```

in the `dashboardBody` and `collapsed = TRUE` in the `dashboardSidebar`.

**app.R**

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Main", tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("dashboard")
        )
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      useShinyjs(),
      tabItems(
        tabItem("tab1",
                column(width = 12,
                       tags$div(id = "main", style = "width: 100%; height: 400px"),
                       tags$script(src = "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.1.0/echarts.min.js"),
                       tags$script(src = "myscript.js")
                )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  addClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**myscript.js**

```
option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
        type: 'line'
    }]
};

var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'), width='100%');
myChart.setOption(option);


$(window).on('resize', function(){
    if(myChart != null && myChart != undefined){
        myChart.resize();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the work-around! If you feel like it, the answer could be further improved by saying something about why this works. Many R programmers (including myself) are not well versed in web development technologies. E.g., what the removal of the class does. A minor thing, but also a potential improvement: seems like the `width=100%` argument doesn't work (according to Echart docs, this argument takes pixels). I added `$(document).ready(function(){
    if(myChart != null && myChart != undefined){
        myChart.resize();
    }
    });` to resize on startup.